# The method toMap() is undefined for the type JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

In the old version `json`(20141113) jar how to solve this **error** `toMap()` showing undefiend for **jsonObject**  eventDto.setEvent_detail(new JSONObject(event.getEvent_detail()).toMap()); in toMap()

```
public class EventDto {
    private Integer storeId;

    private Integer imageId;

    private String event_status;

    private Map<String, Object> event_detail;
            //getter and setter
}





private EventDto getEventDTO(Event event) {
        EventDto eventDto = new EventDto();

        try {
            if (event.getEvent_id() != null) {
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(event, eventDto);
                eventDto.setEvent_detail(new JSONObject(event.getEvent_detail()).toMap());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return eventDto;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to tag a language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Check [covertValue in Mapper API](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class))